# 'router-outlet' is not a known element in angular2

Tags: angular

I've just created a new angular project using the Angular CLI and scaffolded a new route and I am getting error as :

'router-outlet' is not a known element

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Please show code where you are getting this error ?? Also refer StackOverflow guideline to ask better question

Comment: Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 16):

Please add

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
```

in `app.module.ts` and import it in `imports` -

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule
],
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the solution that worked for me, inspired by *gaurav2887* from [this page](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter/issues/1004):

```
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
...    
beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [ MyComponent ],
            imports: [ RouterTestingModule ]
        });
...
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to first import **Routes** & **RouterModule**

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
```

Then import it with root Constant and Export

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

Then Export all the Components you want to implement routing with.

That set...Hope it will work.

Answer (score -1):

The following worked!

Using:

```
"@angular/router": "3.1.2",
```